# Rails, using scopes to filter table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am fairly new to rails and i have to update an existing project. I have an existing database, beforehand it was just one User group, now there should be multiple. Now i want to use the old view, but filter with the help of a dropdown menu, but for some reason i can't work out what i am doing wrong.

Here are the code snippets i changed, since it was working beforehand, i assume my mistake must be somewhere within these lines.

event.rb

```
  scope :men, lambda { { :conditions => ["team_id == ?", 1] } }
  scope :women, lambda { { :conditions => ["team_id == ?", 2] } }
  scope :juniors, lambda { { :conditions => ["team_id == ?", 3] } }
```

events_controller.rb

```
def index
#   @events = Event.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today).order("startdate, starttime")
#   @events = Event.order("startdate, starttime")

if params[:search]
  @events = Event.search(params[:search])
else
  if params[:filter].nil?
    @events = Event.all
  else
    if params[:filter] == "Alle" then @events = Event.all end
    if params[:filter] == "Men" then @events = Event.men end
    if params[:filter] == "Women" then @events = Event.women end 
    if params[:filter] == "Juniors" then @events = Event.juniors end
  end
end
```

end

and the index.html.erb

```
<div class="left">
<%= form_tag events_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <%= select_tag "filter", options_for_select([ "Alle", "Men", "Women", "Juniors" ], params[:filter]), {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'}  %>
<% end %>
```

probably it is a simple mistake. My guess is, that in the index.html.erb i am doing something wrong.

as a follow up, i want to filter just the events which are upcoming, for that i can use the commented part in the controller. can i just add that to the assignmnet in the style of:

```
@events = Event.men.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today).order("startdate, starttime")
```

thanks for the help

Lenny

Answer (score 3):

You should change your scopes to new syntax:

```
scope :men, -> { where(team_id: 1) }
scope :women, -> { where(team_id: 2) }
scope :juniors, -> { where(team_id: 3) }
```

Your controller logic is a little buggy and twisted (checking 5 times filter isnt best way, why checking e.g. if filter is "Men" if you already matched it with "Alle" ?). Here is some help:

```
@events = if params[:search].present?
  Event.search(params[:search].to_s)
else
  case params[:filter]
  when "Men" 
    Event.men
  when "Women" 
    Event.women 
  when "Juniors"
    Event.juniors
  else
    Event.all
  end
end
```

Speaking about view, you shouldnt use inline js, just because its XXI century, and such "quick solutions" are harder to maintain later, so:

```
<div class="left">
<%= form_tag events_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <%= select_tag "filter", options_for_select([ "Alle", "Men", "Women", "Juniors" ], params[:filter]), class: 'my_filter' %>
<% end %>
```

and then add to your events.coffee:

```
$('select.my_filter').on 'change', ->
  $(this).parents('form').submit()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, that helped a bit so far. I have the dropdown menu now and the event.all is displayed by default. But if i select a different option from the menu nothing happens

Comment: Might that be, because i need to declare the script in the .coffee as .live or .on? e.g.
    $('select.my_filter').live "change" ... as i tried, that did not change anything for me

Comment: Dont use live, its already deprecated. Source:
http://api.jquery.com/live/
I fixed my answer, by using jquery .on('change', function() {...})
If you want to use live then use something like this:
$('form.my-form').on('change', 'input', ->

Comment: event with that part added, it does not trigger an action when i select another option. it just displays all of my events in very case.